# create xml file from with in program

Tags: xml, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am making a program, with visual basic, that will show information about contacts. In the program you can make notes about the contact and I have a xml file as a template. My question how do I take the template and fill it with info and save it as an xml file?

template:

```
<Data>
<date_created></date_created>
<short_description></shot_description>
<full_note></full_note>
</Data>
```

Comment: Are you asking for a way to use an XML file as a template, that your program will fill in and then save as a new file, or are you asking how to create an XML file that has the above format/elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option(Xml Literal):

```
Dim xml = <Data>
            <date_created></date_created>
            <short_description></shot_description>
            <full_note></full_note>
          </Data>

Dim xmlDoc As New XmlDocument
xmldoc.LoadXml(xml.ToString)
xmldoc.Save({path})
```

Another option: [xml Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950721.aspx)

Comment: How do I it take the user input and add it to the xml file I am creating?

Comment: Create a node and append it to the document.